# Flutter Stripe how to make the paying customer refaund

Tags: flutter, flutter-stripe

I have 2 flutter apps that separately manage drivers and customer for a ridesharing service and communicate with each other using firebase. I am using the flutter_stripe package to make the payment that happens when the customer makes a request for a drivers. How do I refaund the client if the driver declines the ride? can I copy the intent within the database and do something? Help me...

This is my code for customer app :

```
  Future<void> makePayment() async {
    try {
      final paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('1', 'EUR'); //
      //STEP 2: Initialize Payment Sheet
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            // customFlow: true,
            merchantDisplayName: 'My Shop',
            customerId: paymentIntent['customer'],
            // customerEphemeralKeySecret: 'ephkey_1M...........',
            applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(
              merchantCountryCode: "IT",
            ),
            googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(
              merchantCountryCode: 'IT',
              testEnv: true,
            ),
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['client_secret'],
          ))
          .then((value) {});

      //STEP 3: Display Payment sheet
      displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) async {


          try {
            print("imposto successful a payment status della corsa ------>" + referenceRideRequest!.key.toString());
            FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                .child("ALL Ride Requests")
                .child(referenceRideRequest!.key.toString())
                .child("paymentStatus")
                .set("successful");
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }


      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        throw Exception(error);
      });
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print('Error is:---> $e');

    } catch (e) {
      print('DErrrrrr$e');
    }
  }

  calculateAmount(String amount) {
    final calculatedAmout = (int.parse(amount)) * 100;
    return calculatedAmout.toString();
  }

  createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    print("In Price");
    final dio = Dio();

    try {
      print("In Try");

      var response = await dio.post("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents",
          // url("https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices"),
          // queryParameters: {},
          options: Options(headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${dotenv.env['STRIPE_SECRET']}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }),
          queryParameters: {'amount': calculateAmount(amount), 'currency': currency});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);

        print("Ram::::::::::::Success ");
      } else {
        print(response.data);

        makePayment();
      }
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print("In Try");

      makePayment();
      print(e);
      print("Ram::::::::::::False");
    }
  }
```